# equilibrium and direction field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here I have equilibrium and direction field answer and I am confused about the problem here that has `a` and `b` in it. I also understand how they got the answer  `y = 0,a/b` and I also understand when I see the arrows on the graph if its stable or unstable..When I usually do direction field , the problem only has y's and x's in it so that I can plug in numbers to sketch if its negative, positive or even. What confuses me here is the `a` and `b`. What does `a` and `b` do here ? Do I plug in numbers here like I do with a direction field problem to check if it's negative or positive ?? I would appreciate the explanation.

[image]

Comment: For this case, $a = b$ as Amzoti said.

Comment: so those would be the equalibrium lines to see they are stable or unstable..but how would I check if the arrows are going positive or negative ? where do I plug in the numbers like I do in the direction field ? do I plug it in the original equation ?

Comment: @Amzoti for example y= -2 you would do --> -1(-2) + 1(-2)^2 ? and check if its positive or negative ?

Comment: awesome!...I got it now...it was just a and b that gave me trouble...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a$ and $b$ are arbitrary positive real numbers.  For your problem, we set $y' = 0$ and solve for $y$.  As you said $y = 0$ and $y = \frac{a}{b}$.  Based on the given graph, you see that at $y = 1$, the equilibrium point is unstable, whereas the equilibrium point at $y = 0$ is stable.

If $b$ is negative, then the direction of the field changes.  Otherwise, if $b$ is positive, then we obtain the graph of the field as you have already shown (since you are suppose to sketch the field such that $a = b = 1$).

One determines the direction of the field either by checking the values besides $y = 0$ and $y = \frac{a}{b}$ or by graphing and figuring out the field based on the values of $y'$.  In addition, for the latter method, the values of $y'$ depends on the direction of the field based on the values of the points on the graph.

---

**Algebra**

It's clear that if you check $y = 2$, then $y' > 0$.  If $y = -2$, then $y' > 0$.  If $y = \frac{1}{2}$, then $y' < 0$.  Thus, the field points up at $y < 0$ and $y > 1$ and points down at $0 < y < 1$.

---

**Graphing**

Here is the [link of the graph from Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-y%20%2b%20y%5E2).  We have the following observations:

- Since at $y < 0$ and $y > 1$ we have positive values, the field points up.
- Since at $0 < y < 1$ we have negative values, the field points down.

This is how one studies the directions of the field in "graph"-sense.

Comment: thanks...now I understand that a and b are 1 but what I trying to ask is how would I find if the arrows are going down or up ? do I plug in numbers in the original equation like I do in direction field ?

Comment: I included extra info for my answer because you want to determine the direction of the field.

Comment: thank you so much!...I didnt know you could do it two ways when it comes determining the direction of the field..